# Zoho mail is working properly on localhost but not on the live server with nodemailer

Tags: node.js, reactjs, nodemailer, zoho

package.json

```
      "proxy": {
        "/auth/google": {
          "target": "http://localhost:8000/"
        }
      },
```

ContactForm.jsx

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'

const ContactForm = () => {

    const [fname, setFname] = useState("");
    const [lname, setLname] = useState("");
    const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
    const [subject, setSubject] = useState("");
    const [msg, setMsg] = useState("");
    const [message, setMessage] = useState('');

    useEffect(() => {
        setTimeout(function () {
            setMessage(true)
        }, 9000);
    },
        [message])


    const sendEmail = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();


        setFname("");
        setLname("");
        setEmail("");
        setSubject("");
        setMsg("");

        setMessage(`Thank you ${fname} ${lname} for enquiry. We will back to you asap.`);

        const res = await fetch("/register", {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            }, body: JSON.stringify({
                fname, lname, email, subject, msg
            })
        });

        console.log(res);


    }


    return (
        <>
            <div className="contact-form">
                <div className="contact-form-info">
                    <div className="contact-title">
                        <h3>TELL US YOUR PROJECT</h3>
                    </div>
                    <form id="contact-form">
                        <div className="contact-page-form">
                            <div className="contact-input">
                                <div className="contact-inner">
                                    <input type="text" placeholder="First Name *" id="first-name" value={fname} onChange={(e) => setFname(e.target.value)} />
                                </div>
                                <div className="contact-inner">
                                    <input type="text" placeholder="Last Name *" id="last-name" value={lname} onChange={(e) => setLname(e.target.value)} />
                                </div>
                                <div className="contact-inner">
                                    <input type="text" placeholder="Email *" id="email" value={email} onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)} />
                                </div>
                                <div className="contact-inner">
                                    <input type="text" placeholder="Subject *" id="subject" value={subject} onChange={(e) => setSubject(e.target.value)} />
                                </div>
                                <div className="contact-inner contact-message">
                                    <textarea placeholder="Message *" value={msg} onChange={(e) => setMsg(e.target.value)}></textarea>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div className="contact-submit-btn">
                                <button className="submit-btn" type="submit" onClick={sendEmail} >Send Email</button>
                                <p className="form-messege pt-3">{message}</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </>
    )
}

export default ContactForm;
```

app.js

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const router = require("./routes/router");
const cors = require("cors");

const port = 8000
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());
app.use(router);

app.listen(port,()=>{
    console.log(`Server start on port no : ${port}`)
})
```

router.js

```
const express = require("express");
const router = new express.Router();
const nodemailer = require("nodemailer");

router.post("/register", (req, res) => {

    const { fname, lname, email, subject, msg } = req.body;


    try {
        let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
            host: "smtppro.zoho.in",
            port: 465,
            secure: true,   // true for 465, false for other ports
            auth: {
                user: "info@mydomain.com",
                pass: "myAppPassword",
            },
        });

        const mailOptions = {
            from: "info@mydomain.com",
            cc: "info@mydomain.com",
            to: email,
            subject: "Website Form",
            html: 'First Name : ' + fname + '<br>' +
                'Last Name : ' + lname + '<br>' +
                'Email : ' + email + '<br>' +
                'Subject : ' + subject + '<br>' +
                'Message : ' + msg
        }

        transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
            if (error) {
                console.log("Error", error)
            } else {
                console.log("Email sent" + info.response);
                res.status(201).json({ status: 201, info })
            }
        })
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(401).json({ status: 401, error })
    }
});

module.exports = router;
```

I have been using nodemailer to send emails from my react and node js app, it used to work perfectly on localhost. I deployed to my hosting, it didn't work. Giving this.

```
Response {type: 'basic', url: 'https://example.com/register', redirected: false, status: 200, ok: true, …}
```